# How to remove duplicate rows in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a line in my query in NEO4j using cypher:

```
"WITH *, collect(human.name) as  sample"
```

Which produces results such as:

| Answer |
| --- |
| Bob |
| Sally |
| Bob |
| Bob |
| Sally |

And I would like to remove duplicates such that the answer produces:

| Answer |
| --- |
| Bob |
| Sally |

How can i go about doing this? The line below achieves my desired result but it does not let me continue writing further query lines after the RETURN as "RETURN can only be used at the last line of the query".

```
RETURN DISTINCT sample
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned `DISTINCT` will do the job, Use:

```
WITH collect(DISTINCT human.name) as sample
```

For example, with sample data:

```
MERGE (a:Human{name: "Bob", key: 1})
MERGE (c:Human{name: "Sally", key: 2})
MERGE (b:Human{name: "Bob", key: 3})
MERGE (d:Human{name: "Bob", key: 4})
MERGE (e:Human{name: "Sally", key: 5})
```

And query:

```
MATCH (human:Human)
WITH COLLECT (DISTINCT human.name) as sample
return sample
```

The response is:

```
╒═══════════════╕
│"sample"       │
╞═══════════════╡
│["Bob","Sally"]│
└───────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Can I kindly clarify with you if there is a way to do the reverse later?  I.e. go from the "bob, sally" in one row, to "bob", "sally" each in its individual rows (so 2 rows).

Comment: Later you can unwind if you want